# Samsung Wallet PIN keyboard not working after replacing screen

Tags: keyboard, screen, samsung-pay

I've replaced the screen of my Samsung Galaxy S20 FE and did a factory reset of it. Afterward, I cannot set up Samsung Wallet anymore because I simply cannot tap on the PIN keyboard. I would guess that it is some sort of encryption/certificate that the new screen is missing since it says "safe mode" above the keyboard.

Is there any workaround to this?

Note: I would really like to not have to use Google Wallet.

Comment: Some manufactures are known to include certificates in their replacement parts so the phone can detect changed parts and non-original part. If you use non-original parts then this has most likely an effect on the Knox state. Some apps rely on the Knox security state and refuse to work if the state is non-genuine.